# Deploy Visual Studio 2015 sharepoint2016 web part error

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, web-parts

On my VM, I have got vs2015 and sharepoint server 2016 installed. So when trying to deploy a webpart, I got this error:

#### Error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets(450,5): error : Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Any help is greatly appreciated. tqvm.

P/s: I'm very new to sharepoint.

Comment: Setting MSBuild output verbosity to Detailed or other, then add detail log in your case. (In VS=>Tools=>Options=>Projects and Solutions=>Build and Run=>Select output verbosity.

Comment: you got the solution?